# How to auto mount partition on startup in Xubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, mount, xubuntu, fstab

I want to auto mount all my partitions on startup. This is how my `/etc/fstab` file looks like:

```
proc    /proc   proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid     0       0
#Entry for /dev/sda1 :
UUID=3bf842ea-923b-43fe-b5f9-066fc920aaec       /       ext4    errors=remount-$
#Entry for /dev/sdb1 :
UUID=F0C859BDC8598330   /media/Bas      ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8    $
#Entry for /dev/sda3 :
UUID=146213A76D02F7AD   /media/sda3     ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8    $
UUID=1C33A98704D941F1   /media/sda3     ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8    $
#Entry for /dev/sda5 :
UUID=ba48c631-5652-4ce7-85a3-bda96b353ca7       none    swap    sw      0      $
```

The last line I added myself manually. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: It seems you add a wrong entry (`/media/sda3` is duplicated) please first list the /dev/sda* you have

Comment: Do you want a program that will do it for you automatically ?

Answer (score 1):

You have duplicated lines for the same mount point 
`/media/sda3` appears two times. 
Try creating a new mount point like `/media/newdisk`
and put it in  your `/etc/fstab`
I'm taking your input as example, if `/media/sda3` works, so should this line.

```
UUID=1C33A98704D941F1   /media/newdisk     ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8    $
```

Answer (score -1):

This question is asked and published on a lot of websites and forums. 
Also, fstab is Linux related, not Xubuntu especific.

Comment: I think is a valid point to mention that it is Xubuntu;  not everybody can guess what is Xubuntu specific, what is Ubuntu specific or what is Linux specific; and the ones that do know, can infer from that.